# Microsoft-Teams Get all messages channel with their replies through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to retrieve all messages with their replies in one request?
From what I read to retrieve replies of messages we need to make this request:

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/{id}/replies/{id}
```

But it does not seem efficient to read through every message and check if it has replies.

Comment: It's two-step process. First you need to read all the messages and then read all replies for each message. Currently, there is no API which does this in one go.

Comment: Thanks. That would be good to add a field that tells me if the message contains reply or not to prevent unnecessary query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will get to this (hopefully by mid 2019) but it won't be via a per-message flag that tells you whether you need to make another call. Rather, we will support a `$expand` parameter that will fetch a set of messages and their replies (likely within a specified time range or since a certain timestamp).

Comment: Do you have an update on this? Just tried it and it does not work yet.

Comment: /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/{id}/replies  API should also have delta link facility in reply, As for now iterating through each reply every time is inefficient in number is more.